# how to allocate memory for array of pointers to struct and then free it?

Tags: c, malloc

I want to allocate space for an array of pointers to structs so here is what I did.

```
typedef struct A_example{
  struct B_example* B_array[MAX_SIZE];
} A
typedef struct B_example{
  int a;
}B
A A_array[MAX_SIZE2];
```

so to allocate memory for B_Array for an element of A_array I do this:

```
A_array[current_element].B_array[i] = (struct B_example*)malloc(sizeof(struct B_example));
```

is this correct? and how should I free the memory for this?

Comment: Why an array of pointers instead of an array of structs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your allocation appears to be correct (aside from the standard advice that is normally given to not cast the return of `malloc`). You can `free` it via `free(A_array[current_element].B_array[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't want to have a memory leak.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: The question was "**how** should I free the memory", not "**should** I free the memory".

Comment: Then use the free() function, its parameter is the pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc.